# Delete sheet where name like

Tags: vba, excel

How can I delete sheet where the sheet name like

```
Left(SheetExists.Name, 16) = "Mgt Report as at"
```

Tried:

```
Sheets(Left(SheetExists.Name, 16) = "Mgt Report as at").Delete
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Something like this (not tested):

```
For Each s in ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    If Left(s.Name, 16) = "Mgt Report as at" Then
        s.Delete
    End If
Next s
```

Answer (score 5):

Another way using `LIKE` as you have mentioned in the title of your question.

Also note, in such a scenario, you have to be careful when you are deleting the sheets. See the comments in the code below.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        If ws.Name Like "Mgt Report as at" & "*" Then
            '~~> This check is required to ensure that you don't get an error
            '~~> if there is only one sheet left and it matches the delete criteria
            If ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count = 1 Then
                MsgBox "There is only one sheet left and you cannot delete it"
            Else
                '~~> This is required to supress the dialog box which excel shows
                '~~> When you delete a sheet. Remove it if you want to see the
                '~~~> Dialog Box
                Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                ws.Delete
                Application.DisplayAlerts = True
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```